# $a + b = c + c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

So I have the following problem: $a + b = c + c.
I want to prove that the equation has infinitely many relatively prime integer solutions.

What I did first was factor the right side to get: 
(

Comment: Is the question $a^2+b^2=c^5+c$ or $a^5+b^5=c^5+c$?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped its a^2  + b^2 = c^5 + c

Comment: If you know that primes congruent to $1$ mod $4$ can be written as sums of squares (and if you know there are infinitely many such primes), you should be good to go.

Comment: Excuse me, but what is the unknown value?

Comment: Come to think of it, it suffices to know (or show) that $c=5^n$ can always be written as the sum of two relatively prime squares.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $c=u^2+v^2$ then you have $$(uc^2+v)^2+(vc^2-u)^2=c(c^4+1)$$ and you want $uc^2+v$ and $vc^2-u$ to be coprime.

Now just choose $u=1$ so that the expressions are $a=c^2+v$ and $b=vc^2-1$ with $c=v^2+1$

Note then that that a common factor of $a$ and $b$ is also a factor of $va-b=v^2+1=c$ and $ac^2-b=c^4+1$, but $c$ and $c^4+1$ are coprime.

---

So you get a family of solutions with

$c=v^2+1$ and

$a=c^2+v=v^4+2v^2+v+1$ and

$b=vc^2-1=v^5+2v^3+v-1$

[Which, I notice is just Sam's parametric solution with $u=1$. It should be obvious what to do to generalise.]

Comment: Hi, I need some help understanding. How did you generalize this?

Comment: @user604720 Just keeping in the $u$ rather than setting $u=1$ and working through the logic gives the parametric family. Along the way you get $va-ub=c$ and $ac^2-b=u(c^4+1)$ and it is not so easy to prove coprime for the parametric solutions because of the factor $u$, but since this starts with an arbitrary $c=u^2+v^2$ one can pick $u$ and $v$ to make this obvious. $u=1$ is an easy choice.

Answer (score 3):

Above equation shown below has parametric solution:

$(a^2+b^2)=c(c^4+1)$

$a=u^5+uv^4+2u^3v^2+v$

$b=v^5+u^4v+2u^2v^3-u$

$c=u^2+v^2$

For $(u,v)=(3,2)$  we get:

$(509^2+335^2)=13(13^4+1)$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. I see you've used the OP's idea of letting $c=u^2+v^2$. And it is clear that the RHS's outer terms are $u^{10}$ and $v^{10}$, hence your $u^5$ and $v^5$ terms. But how did you find out the other terms?

Comment: @RosieF I have put a solution which begins in a different place, and shows an infinite number of coprime pairs - it turns out to be essentially the same as this and shows where the numbers come from.

Comment: Hi, how did you go about putting the equation in parametric form?

Answer (score 0):

In the equation:

$$X^2+Y^2=Z^5+Z$$

I think this formula should be written in a more general form:

$$Z=a^2+b^2$$

$$X=a(a^2+b^2)^2+b$$

$$Y=b(a^2+b^2)^2-a$$

And yet another formula:

$$Z=\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$$

$$X=\frac{(a-b)(a^2+b^2)^2-4(a+b)}{8}$$

$$Y=\frac{(a+b)(a^2+b^2)^2+4(a-b)}{8}$$

$a,b$ - arbitrary integers.

Solutions can be written as follows:

$$Z=\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{2}$$

$$X=\frac{((a^2+b^2)^4+4)a^2+2((a^2+b^2)^4-4)ab-((a^2+b^2)^4+4)b^2}{8}$$

$$Y=\frac{((a^2+b^2)^4-4)a^2-2((a^2+b^2)^4+4)ab-((a^2+b^2)^4-4)b^2}{8}$$

where $a,b$ - any integers asked us.

Well, a simple solution:

$$Z=(a^2+b^2)^2$$

$$X=a^2+2(a^2+b^2)^4ab-b^2$$

$$Y=(a^2+b^2)^4a^2-2ab-(a^2+b^2)^4b^2$$